# Static IP with DDWRT and Linksys E1200

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I'm using a static ip with **DDWRT and Linksys E1200** . 
The router is using startup linux scripts from TorGuard . 
Now with that provider im using 5 hardwired pc's to that modem and the download speeds are not going above 4mbps when my normal ISP download speed is around 80mbps . Does the problem with the router itself OR the IP provider or my original ISP blocking something.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your last sentence, in particular, is difficult to understand.

Comment: Oh , just noticed that i did a mistake . Edited it

Comment: The static IP is provided by your ISP, correct? If so, you have an extra 'or' in your last sentence that makes it sound like you're asking about three possible causes (router, IP provider, or ISP blocking something).

Comment: Nevermind , the issue was a very weak CPU of the router, it were working on 100% cpu usage and the router didnt survived a reset . thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. Please post that as an answer to your question. Someone else may have the same issue and find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a very weak CPU of the router, it were working on 100% cpu usage and the router didnt survived a reset. One of the best routers you can get for this kind of use is LINKSYS WRT1900ACS DUAL-BAND WI-FI ROUTER WITH ULTRA-FAST 1.6 GHZ CPU.